# A product with a value of $29 has 15% GST added to it.

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

not really good with the GST side ot things tried doing a lot of stuff like dividing and multiplying I am not sure what the answer is.

this is my answer 33.35

is this correct?

Comment: $\$29\times1.15=\$33.35$

Comment: ok thank you very much I know how to do it now

Answer (score 0):

Yes; $\$29\times1.15=\$33.35$.